# asp.net cms systems

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I'm most a LAMP developer but need to recommend a asp.net CMS solution to a client?  What are the leading CMS solutions in the .net environment?

Comment: This should be a community wiki question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)
- [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)

You may also take a look at http://cmsmatrix.org/ for more options

Comment: Another +1 for CMS Matrix. I asked a similar question waaaay back when and using the matrix was able to help me make a better decision, and evaluate some options I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 3):

- [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)
- [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)
- [AxCMS](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/02/437220.aspx)
- [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sitecore.net

Answer (score 2):

[Graffiti CMS](http://graffiticms.com/) is a non-open source CMS solution by [Telligent](http://telligent.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is [www.kitgui.com](http://www.kitgui.com) which is agnostic to the server-side approach but is still a programmatic approach through REST instead of doing it through FTP. This is the most flexible of all because I made it that way.

Answer (score -1):

DNN, Umbraco, Kentico, MojoPortal, Orcchard to name a few good ones.

Here's a good comparison matrix --> [ASp.net CMS Comparison Matrix](http://www.findbestwebhosting.com/web-hosting-blog/index.php/5-best-asp-net-content-management-systems)